# How can I change the status code including custom error page

Tags: nginx, http-status-codes, custom-error-pages

I'm changing the status code 403 to 404. I just don't want to let the user know that there is a restricted page at all. This works fine with the following config:

```
error_page 403 =404 @404;   

location @404 {
    return 404;
}
```

Now, I would like to return a custom 404 error page. But the status code sent to the user should always be 404 (when 403 occurs). How can I get both to work?

**Edit:**

I hoped sth. like this would work, but it doesn't.

```
location @404 {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    internal;
    return 404 "/custom_404.html";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was a `deny` statement. That statement is blocking everything including the access to any custom error page. The solution is to add `allow all` inside the custom error page block to revoke the inherited deny.

```
error_page 403 404 =404 /custom_404.html;

location = /custom_404.html {
    allow all;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    internal;
}
```

original source:

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-nginx-custom-error-403-page-configuration/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
error_page 404 /404.html;
location = /404.html {
        root /var/www/error/;
        internal;
}
```

Comment: Not working. Nginx is ignoring that because of the return statement.